# Change message name

Tags: web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

Here is the part of my WSDL. I'm using the code first approach.

```
<portType name="MyWebService">
     <operation name="echoString"/>
         <input message="echoString"/>
         <output message="echoStringResponse"/>
     </operation>
 </portType>
```

What annotation should I add or change so to change this

```
<input message="echoString"/>
```

to read as

```
<input message="echoStringRequest"/>
```

Thanks all.

Comment: I know its a very old thread.. did you find any solution? Im struggling with this issue now...

Answer (score 2):

I am quite surprised myself, but after trying for a while I looked into the spec and it seems you cannot really do this in jax-ws (except in a non-standard way, depending on the implementation). Here is what the [jax-ws 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxws-2_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says on this issue. See *Java to WSDL 1.1 Mapping*, Section 3.5, page 32:

> The value of a wsdl:message element’s name attribute is not
>   significant but by convention it is normally equal to the
>   corresponding operation name for input messages and the operation name
>   concatenated with “Response” for output messages. Naming of fault
>   messages is described in section section 3.7.

So the only option that comes to my mind is to rename your operation, for example by changing or adding a `@WebMethod` annotation. Here is an example:

```java
@WebMethod(operationName = "echoStringRequest")
public String echoString(String echoStringRequest) {
    return echoStringRequest;
}
```

This will generate the following `portType`:

```
<portType name="MyWebService">
   <operation name="echoStringRequest">
      <input message="tns:echoStringRequest"></input>
      <output message="tns:echoStringRequestResponse"></output>
   </operation>
</portType>
```

The decision of whether you are more happy with this version is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem myself recently and stumbled upon this thread multiple times. In our application we have a JAX-WS servlet which must use the format of ...Request and ...Response.

After a few days of searching, I found the solution.

Let's say your echoStringRequest has one String property that should be echoed back in the response.

```
class EchoMessage {
    private String message;

    //add getter and setter
}
```

First add this annotation to the web service class:

```
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
```

Then annotate your web service method like this:

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "echoStringResponse")
public EchoMessage echoString (@WebParam(name = "echoStringRequest") EchoMessage inputMessage) {
    ...
}
```

Without the parameterStyle BARE annotation, JAX-WS would automatically generate messages like this:

```
<echoString>
    <echoStringRequest>
        ...
    </echoStringRequest>
</echoString>
```

With the annotation, the outer element  does not exist anymore.

The @WebParam and @ReturnType annotations are needed to determine the names of the root elements in the SOAP request and response body.